# Implementing Multiplayer OS with AppKit

Tags: python, macos, core-graphics, appkit

I'm trying to implement a multiplayer OS where for now, cursor1 is controlled by the user's mouse movements and cursor2 is simulated by simple brownian motion. Since I'm new to the AppKit and Quartz API, I'd appreciate some direction. Following is the code I've already written:

```
import Quartz
import AppKit
import random
import ctypes
import time
import objc

def create_cursor_window(position):
    rect = AppKit.NSMakeRect(position[0], position[1], 24, 24)
    window = AppKit.NSWindow.alloc().initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(
        rect, AppKit.NSBorderlessWindowMask, AppKit.NSBackingStoreBuffered, False)
    window.setOpaque_(False)
    window.setBackgroundColor_(AppKit.NSColor.clearColor())
    window.setLevel_(AppKit.NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 1)
    window.setIgnoresMouseEvents_(True)
    return window

def load_custom_cursor_image(image_path):
    return AppKit.NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(image_path)

def main():
    cursor1_image_path = "./assets/cursor_1.png"
    cursor2_image_path = "./assets/cursor_2.png"

    cursor1_image = load_custom_cursor_image(cursor1_image_path)
    cursor2_image = load_custom_cursor_image(cursor2_image_path)

    cursor1_position = (0, 0)
    cursor2_position = (0, 0)

    cursor1_window = create_cursor_window(cursor1_position)
    cursor2_window = create_cursor_window(cursor2_position)

    def update_cursor_position(event, cursor_position):
        cursor_position = (event.locationInWindow().x, event.locationInWindow().y)
        return cursor_position
    
    def update_cursor_position_brownian(cursor_position):
        dx = random.uniform(-5, 5)
        dy = random.uniform(-5, 5)
        cursor_position = (cursor_position[0] + dx, cursor_position[1] + dy)
        return cursor_position 

    def draw_cursor(window, cursor_image, cursor_position):
        if cursor_image is not None:
            content_view = AppKit.NSView.alloc().initWithFrame_(window.frame())
            window.setContentView_(content_view)

            def draw(_self, _cmd, _rect):
                cursor_image.drawAtPoint_fromRect_operation_fraction_(
                    cursor_position, AppKit.NSZeroRect, AppKit.NSCompositeSourceOver, 1.0
                )

            view_draw = objc.selector(draw, signature=b"v@:@{NSRect=dd{NSPoint=dd}{NSSize=dd}}")
            objc.classAddMethod(AppKit.NSView, b"drawRect:", view_draw)
            content_view.setNeedsDisplay_(True)
        else:
            print("Error: Cursor image not loaded.")

    def update_virtual_screen():
        AppKit.NSScreen.screens()[0].display()

    app = AppKit.NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    app.setActivationPolicy_(AppKit.NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular)

    while True:
        event = app.nextEventMatchingMask_untilDate_inMode_dequeue_(AppKit.NSEventMaskAny, AppKit.NSDate.distantPast(), AppKit.NSDefaultRunLoopMode, True)
        if event:
            if event.type() == AppKit.NSEventTypeMouseMoved:
                cursor1_position = update_cursor_position(event, cursor1_position)
        
        cursor2_position = update_cursor_position_brownian(cursor2_position)

        draw_cursor(cursor1_window, cursor1_image, cursor1_position)
        draw_cursor(cursor2_window, cursor2_image, cursor2_position)
        # update_virtual_screen()

        time.sleep(0.01)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
> (venv) shawn@shawns-Mac-mini ai_os % python3 multiplayer.py Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/shawn/Documents/Projects/ai_os/multiplayer.py", line 81, in
> <module>
>     main()   File "/Users/shawn/Documents/Projects/ai_os/multiplayer.py", line 74, in
> main
>     draw_cursor(cursor1_window, cursor1_image, cursor1_position)   File "/Users/shawn/Documents/Projects/ai_os/multiplayer.py", line 55,
> in draw_cursor
>     objc.classAddMethod(AppKit.NSView, b"drawRect:", view_draw)   File "/Users/shawn/Documents/Projects/ai_os/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/objc/_category.py",
> line 25, in classAddMethod
>     return classAddMethods(cls, [sel])
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ objc.BadPrototypeError: Python signature doesn't match implied Objective-C signature for <function
> main.<locals>.draw_cursor.<locals>.draw at 0x108523380>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Python but (why) are you trying create a new `NSView` and replace `drawRect:` in a loop?